# resizing images in wordpress css html

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm developing a blog on wordpress, the theme is Marlene.

So, I have a post and by default the image in this post has the resolution 835x577, which is great for me ([example of the post](http://cu33132.tmweb.ru/expotory/2016/06/01/tractorrace/))

But I also have the page "News", in which I want to display the list of  all my news posts. And in this page I need to resize the image to 400 x auto ([link to news section](http://cu33132.tmweb.ru/expotory/category/news/)).

The problem is that when I'm changing the size of that image then it automatically changes the size of the image inside this post (835x577).

So somehow I need to break this connection. Think I need to create second class with different width and height, but do not know how I can do it automatically in wordpres.

Hope that you could understand me and can help) 
Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: This is what thumbnails are for. Try setting the correct sizes in Media > Settings, and note that changes will only apply to newly loaded images (not the existing ones). To apply changes to existing images you will need to use a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Why not precede the rule with a selector specific to the page in question? E.g: `.archive .post-thumbnail img` - this will only apply to images on summary/archive pages.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError this could be exactly what I need. Could you please provide some more info ?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError when I'm using .post-432 .post-thumbnail img{
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
it changes the size of the image everywhere. But I need only on specific page

Comment: @O.Telegin Take another look at the `body`classes for your wordpress pages and think about where you need these rules to be applied. If you only need them for category pages, use `.archive`; if you only need them for post pages, use `.single-post`; if you only need them applied to a specific category, use `.category-news`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce a layout that is different to the default for the theme you are using, then the simplest way to do that is to [create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).  This lets you use all the code that is in the parent theme, and you can still apply updates and security fixes to your theme, but allows you to add extra bits and pieces such as [custom image sizes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

You'd add the function to the functions.php file of your new child theme.

Alternatively, if that is literally the only thing you want to do that isn't as provided by the theme by default - ie, you  just want to add one line of CSS to format the image size on that one page - you could use a plugin such as [Header and Footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer/) or [Add Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/) to just tweak that one element.

However, I would recommend using a child theme.  You might only want to tweak one line of CSS now, but in a few months when you have other amends to do, having a child theme already properly set up and understanding how to use it will save you work ;-)